# Getting HTTP ERROR 500 on MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have quite some experience with PHP and MySQL, but I have always been working on already set up servers. Now I have my own server (it's actually just a webspace) but it still has all of the standard settings. I have following problems with those:

I set up a connection to my database.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("mydatabase", "myuser", "mypw", "mydatabasename");
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
  echo "Error: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  exit();
} else {
  echo "succesfully connected";
}
```

Which gives me the output `succesfully connected`, as you would expect. If I want to do a simple query like this

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare ("SELECT id FROM Users") {
    $stmt -> execute();
    $stmt -> bind_result($id);
    while($stmt -> fetch) {
        echo $id;
    }
}
```

I get a blank `HTTP ERROR 500`. The SQL query works fine in PHPmyAdmin though.

What I did so far is:

- Checking the Error log (did not contain any errors)
- Trying to add `error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` in front of my script (did not change anything)
- Trying to find my `php.ini`-file to modify (did not find it on the server)

If anyone could help me out and tell me how to get the mysql working, that would be great. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: sometimes error 500 come from syntax errors, in your case you forgot a round bracket here: `if ($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare ("SELECT id FROM Users")) {` (2 closing)

Comment: Dude no way. How could I not see this !? Thank you very much though, it work's now :D

Comment: no problem, have a good coding!